# Transiting through Dubai, from Terminal 3 to 2

Tags: transit, dubai, lounges

I am arriving into Terminal 3 transiting out of Terminal 2, 5.5 hours later.

Is it possible to book time in the Marhaba Lounge in Terminal 3, then move to Terminal 2 for my flight?

Or cant you get access to the lounges if you are transiting through to Terminal 2?

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**, the [Marhaba Lounge](http://www.marhabaservices.com/english/our-services/airport-lounges) is open to all paying passengers.  Bookings aren't really necessary unless you want to be escorted to/from your gate.

If you're connecting from Emirates to Flydubai, you can use the [shuttle service](http://www.emirates.com/au/english/plan_book/connecting_with_flydubai/connecting_with_flydubai.aspx) and do not need to pass through immigration or pick up bags.  But if you are flying any other combination of flights, I would advise you to forget the lounge in T3: instead complete all formalities, transfer, check back in, and only then go to the Marhaba Lounge in T2.  It's admittedly overpriced and crappy, but I'd rather pay the extra $10/hr than risk missing my onward flight.